# Upgrading old Ubuntu to current

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I have a Ubuntu machine running ubuntu 16. I want to upgrade it to the most recent version, but the hints on how to do this fail. According to webpages it should be:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

But I get the messages that 0 packages have been upgraded. What can I do? Change some pathes to the repoitories? How?

Comment: First Ubuntu 16 is not supported. Second I have my doubts you can upgrade from OS from 2017 to OS from 2023, 6 years is a long period. Better create backup and start with fresh installation.

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver/ - repeat for 22

Comment: You need to preferably create a backup first, then run `do-release-upgrade` and pray.

Comment: It is possible to 'do-release-upgrade' between LTS versions stepwise indicated by the answer by Steven Kitt, but it is a slow process with many obstacles. So it is likely to fail somewhere. I suggest that you backup what you want to keep from the current installed system, and then make a fresh installation of the newest LTS version, now 22.04.2 LTS. After that you can copy back your personal files (and maybe some settings, maybe even re-use the whole /home directory as a separate partition). This way you have to make fresh installations of application programs, and also get rid of old cruft.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean 16.04, you can still upgrade to 18.04 which has only just gone out of general support — but I don’t know how long that will remain true.

To upgrade, back your system up, then

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If all goes well, this will upgrade to 18.04. Then another

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

will upgrade to 20.04, and another iteration will upgrade to 22.04, the current LTS release.

Comment: The OP needs to change the repositories to the archived ones first.

Comment: @ChanganAuto it worked for me without changing the repositories.

Comment: How long ago was that? And with or without ESM?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I tested this just before writing my answer, without ESM.